# Latin for "worth a hundred times its weight in gold"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

I'm trying to figure out how to say something is "worth a hundred times its weight in gold" in Latin, and everything I come up with feels cumbersome, unLatinate, and unclear. *Hoc textīle centuplex pretium reddet quam ipsīus aurī pondus* is the best I've been able to do, and that, if it means anything at all (which I doubt) is just gross.

What would be an elegant way to say this? And, for the sake of thoroughness, what would be an elegant way to say simply that something is "worth its weight in gold"?

(Obviously the Romans would probably have just said something like *maximī pretiī cōnstat*, which would certainly do, but I'm hoping to be a little more specific.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest this:

> Haec merx pondere suo [centuplici] in auro constat.

The most important way to remove clumsiness is to use *constare* with *ablativus pretii*.
I'm not sure whether *in auro* is a good choice.
Other options I thought of were *auri* or the adjective *aureo* to modify *pondere*.